Why is this problem non convex in case $B$ has negative entries?
\begin{align}
\min \quad &cx+dy\\
Ax + By    &\leq b\\
y          &= |x|
\end{align}
where $b, d\geq 0$.
I have this problem and I was told that B always has to have non-negative entries otherwise it may not be convex. But to me all constraints (and the objective) seem linear so I have no clear intuition what is the problem with B.

The constraint $y=|x|$ is not linear, and the set of all $(x,y)$ satisfying this constraint is not convex. Hence further structure is needed to make the problem convex.

yeah but if it is not convex i should be able to find a local mimum that is not global right? i can't think of any

you can still have all locals are global for nonconvex problems
